# How to ignore case in regex

Tags: regex

I want to check if a string contains two words "hello world". I am using something like this:

```
str = " aa  bbb  hEllo accc woRld"
str.matches( "(.*)" + "hello" + "(.*)" + "world" + "(.*)" );
```

How do I execute this regular expression as case-insensitive?

Comment: "(.)"  should be "(.*)"

Comment: Use the `i` modifier for case-insensitive..how to use that depends on the language, though.

Answer (score 8):

Try and put the [case-insensitive modifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) `(?i)` at the start of the regex:

```
 str.matches( "(?i)(.)" + "hello" + "(.)" + "world" + "(.*)" );
```

Answer (score 3):

Typically there is a flag that you can set. For many languages such as PHP/JS you would write your regex like: `/REGEX/i` with the `i` after your delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this:

```
str.matches( "(.*)" + "([hH])" + "([eE])" + "([lL])" + "([lL])" + "([oO])"  + "(.*)" + "([wW])" + "([oO])" + "([rR])" + "([lL])" + "([dD])" + "(.*)" );
```

Comment: This is an lousy way of doing it. Too much typing. One can use (?i) modifier or convert the string to lower before comparing it.

Comment: Ah sorry, wasn't aware of this at the time

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a more efficient way than this awnser but anyway... 
You can use the operator  **|** *(or)* for each letter of both *"hello"* and *"world"* strings.

For instance with *hello* :

```
(H | h)(E | e)(L | l){2}(O | o)
```

Which means *H or h* then *E or e* then *L or l* (2 times) then *O or o*

I did not test this, but hope it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

You can just lower case the string and compare it.

```
str = "dffdfHellodasfWorld"
re.findall("(.*)" + "hello" + "(.*)" + "world" + "(.*)", str.lower())
```

This is in python BTW.

Notice the str.lower()